# Magento - huge number of db queries x page

Tags: sql, magento, catalog

I would to know what is the right average number of db queries in a standard installation of magento for catalog pages, because I think to have a big problem with my pages.

My catalog page does about 2000 queries! This is too much and I think that is the reason that my pages are so slow.

Furthermore if you open magento toolbar (at top right) and open queries's table, you can see that more queries are executed many times, query like this:

```
SELECT `eav_attribute_set`.* FROM `eav_attribute_set` WHERE (eav_attribute_set.attribute_set_id='10')
```

And it seems to be a loop.

Now I have to find the problem, maybe some bad extension or bad custom code, but what could be the right number of queries for catalog pages?

Comment: suggestion to remove the link if it's really doing that many queries per page load. You don't want your server to go down, do you?

Comment: nono! please! :) but this is a staging server....do you know how many queries are the right average? so i have a big problem :(

Comment: I've ran a test on a catalog product list page on a fresh Enterprise installation, resulting in around 80 queries. So there is a big difference. You might want to go to `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql` and set the following variables to `true`: `$_debug`, `$_logAllQueries` and `$_logCallStack`.

Especially the last one `$_logCallStack` might come in handy. It logs the backtrace of those methods that triggered the query. The logfile can be found under `/var/debug/`.

Comment: @D.Milito just to clarify - I wasn't threatening! - I was advising :)

Comment: You should have a look on the attribute_set with the id 10. Might be products, but I don't think so. I think some extension is badly coded and makes many ->load() calls, so there are many querys fired.

Comment: Hi guys, today i'm working with this page and i arrive until about 270 queries! It's wow in confront of 2000! :)
Now can you check if my page has yet some performance's problems, please? 
thx very much to all for your tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim Hofman's answer (with wee-developer toolbar installed) was very useful to understand which queries were bad coded by developer before me.

Almost all these queries were load() to retrieve the full product when needed only one product's attribute, so i edited the code.

thx for replies! :)